# Check if a list is a palindrome?

Tags: java, list, palindrome, deque

I have to check if a given list is a palindrome.
It worked all times except for when I tried with big number like -1000000000.
I don't know why is that, I think Integer is big enough to work with the given numbers.
Any ideas why this is not working for this particular test:

```
l: [1, 1000000000, -1000000000, -1000000000, 1000000000, 1]
Output:
false
Expected Output:
true
```

This is my solution:

```
// Singly-linked lists are already defined with this interface:
// class ListNode<T> {
//   ListNode(T x) {
//     value = x;
//   }
//   T value;
//   ListNode<T> next;
// }
//
boolean solution(ListNode<Integer> node) {
        ListNode<Integer> current = node;
        Deque<Integer> list = new ArrayDeque<>();

        while (current != null) {
            list.push(current.value);
            current = current.next;
        }

        current = node;
        while (!list.isEmpty()) {
            Integer el = list.poll();
            System.out.print(el + " ");
            if (el != current.value) {
                return false;
            }

            current = current.next;
        }

        return true;
}
```

Comment: The `==` and `!=` are not for comparing objects, only for comparing primitives. `Integer` is an object, not a primitive.

Comment: But then why is it working for some numbers, for example when I tried with 10 instead of -1_000_000_000 it worked fine?

Comment: @vanderwaal Because Integers between -128 and 127 are cached so numerically equal values in that range share the same reference.

Comment: Do you need to use your Single-Linked List implementation?  You can do this much more efficiently with a raw array or ArrayList comparing list[i] with list[length-i]